# Initializers in protocols in Swift must be designated. Why is that so?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, initialization, protocols

If you try to create a `protocol` in Swift that includes a `convenience initialiser`, you will be immediately scolded by the compiler:

```
protocol Zizo{
    convenience init(a:String, b:Int)
}
```

> Convenience initializer not allowed in non class type.

Is there any reason for this limitation? It just doesn't make sense to me.

What could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because, it makes no sense. `protocol` only defines implementers have required methods and properties. It does not define implementation detail. When `protocol` requires `init(a:String, b:Int)`, you can implement it as either designated or convenience initializer, as you like.

```
protocol Zizo{
    init(a:String, b:Int)
}

class Foo:Zizo {
    init() {
    }
    convenience required init(a:String, b:Int) {
        self.init()
    }
}
class Bar:Foo {
    override convenience init() {
        self.init(a:"baz", b:42)
    }
    required init(a:String, b:Int) {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

As you can see, `protocol` forces `init(a:String, b:Int)` being **`required`** initializer, but does nothing about "convenience" or "designated".

Answer (score 2):

In case you'd still like to do this, you could consider putting a static function in the protocol instead:

```
protocol Zizo {
     static func make(withA a: String, b: Int) -> Self
}
```

this does get a little hairy when used in a class inheritance tree.